# AUTO_CLOSE' is not supported

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, installation

I have to install a software on a server with a fresh installation of
SQL server (I have checked the requirements and all is fine). During the installation i have this error :

> Database error 10794: The operation 'AUTO_CLOSE' is not supported with databases that have a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup.
> The operation 'AUTO_CLOSE' is not supported with databases that have a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup.

I have tried to set manually into -> %db% -> properties -> filegroup, but I get the same error.

Comment: You might try `ALTER DATABASE model SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;` and retrying the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the installation on sql server wrong , because i messed some packages to install . After a new full installation the problem is solved,

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.